# bxslider enable mouse swipe (Click+drag) on desktop browser

Tags: bxslider

I am using bxslider.

The touchEnabled config for my slider is working fine on mobile devices.

I would like to enable a mouse swipe (Click+drag) on desktop browsers. Is this mod easily possible with the plugin?

Thanks

Comment: Did your find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this extension https://gist.github.com/connected/f907145b51a033aa13e0fbfe0ffaed74

include this js after the bxslider, which adds a new param 'mouseDrag' to the bxslider {options} - set this to true when initializing the slider with options

Comment: Thank for the Tip. I will check it out.